# Why does make insist that the files are up to date

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, freebsd

Consider this simple example of a Makefile on FreeBSD.

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
     gcc -o hello hello.o

hello.o: hello.c
     gcc -c hello.c

clean:
     rm hello.o hello
```

And whatever I do, change hello.c, **or even if I change the content in the Makefile to complete nonsense**, make says:

```
`makefile' is up to date.
```

What could be an explanation whats going on there?

Comment: What is `m`? I don't see it in the makefile.

Comment: Sorry, typo should be the Makefile. If i run this Makefile with gmake instead of FreeBSDs make, it just works. Whats the difference between make an gmake on FreeBSD?

Comment: Your error message still doesn't match the shown makefile. You might want to refresh how to create a [mcve]. Also please tell us how you use the `make` command. What arguments do you provide?

Comment: What is the name of your makefile? Is it something other than "makefile"? Is there a file named "makefile" in your working directory?

Comment: And how are you running `make`?  The output you present does not match the makefile content, because "`makefile' is up to date" indicates that the name of the target that `make` was trying to build was "makefile".

Comment: It's clear you're trying to run the command `make makefile`.  That's not how make should be invoked.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Running.html  You say you're on FreeBSD, but you also list `gnu-make` as a tag... note that the default version of make that comes with FreeBSD is not GNU make.  However, all versions of make are invoked in more or less the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have small mess with makefiles. Please note that (for GNU Make): `By default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.` - make sure you haven't created GNUmakefile`

When it comes to `FreeBSD` based `make` it will be: `If no -f makefile makefile option is given, make will try to open 'makefile' then 'Makefile' in order to find the specifications.`

The only case, I can imagine, follows:

```
> cat Makefile
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    cc -o hello hello.o


hello.o: hello.c
    cc -c hello.c

clean:
    rm hello.o hello
> make
cc -c hello.c
cc -o hello hello.o
> ./hello
Hello world!
> make clean
rm hello.o hello
> touch makefile
> echo "makefile:" > .depend
> make
`makefile' is up to date.
```